# converting for loop into assembly without initial test

Tags: c, for-loop, assembly, x86-64

A function `test_two` has the following overall structure:

```
long test_two(unsigned long x) {

  long val = 0;
  int i;

  for(i=64; i != 0; i--) {
   val = (val<<1)|(x & 0x1);
   x>>=1;
  }

 return val;
}
```

the gcc  C compiler generates the following assembly code:

```
test_two:
 movl $64, %edx
 movl $0, %eax
.L10:
 movq %rdi, %rcx
 andl $1, %ecx
 addq %rax, %rax
 orq %rcx, %rax
 shrq %rdi
 subq $1, %rdx
 jne .L10
 rep ret
```

I misunderstood about cmp instruction. So I edited my original quenstion and I hope some people are not confused my question. Sorry about them.

Comment: `for(i=64 , i != 0 , i--)` does not compile. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Instructions like `addq` do not only process the operation, they also set some flags dependent on the result of the operation, like the zero flag. `jne` performs a jump, if the zero flag is not set.

Comment: Your asm doesn't match your C, even if you change the `,` to `;` in the `for`.  `short` is a 16-bit type in both the x86-64 System V ABI, and in Windows x64, so you get `subw`.    https://godbolt.org/z/Jq6EZb  (But the compiler can promote most of the other operations to dword operand-size for efficiency because signed overflow is UB.)  More importantly, the structure is different: it starts with `movl $64, %edx`, and zeroing EAX like you'd expect from the C source.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, you are right. I think the textbook is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional jumps only check condition codes (in this case, ZF), and so do not always need to follow `cmp`. While condition codes are set by `cmp`, they are also set by other operations, including `add` and `sub`, which will set the ZF flag when the result is zero.

It seems that `%rdi` corresponds to `x`, which follows the typical argument passing convention. `val<<1` was converted to the equivalent `addq %rax, %rax`.

You can see the bitwise and and bitwise or instructions (`andl $1, %ecx` and `orq %rcx, %rax`). The assignment to `val` is done with the `or`.

Then you have `x>>=1` as `shrq %rdi` followed by your loop condition and return.

Comment: Starting with `rdx=1` and using `addq $1, %rdx` / jnz as the loop condition will loop `2^64 - 1` times.  It's not an equivalent loop (assuming the source was supposed to be `for(i=64 ; i != 0 ; i--)`.  That's just inexplicable, and one of the reasons the question was downvoted and is unanswerable.  Same with the `mov $65, %eax`.   This code looks like gcc output (based on the label name and using one-operand `shrq`), and it's under the `test_two:` label, not `test_two.ipo_clone.123` or whatever, so it's the stand-alone definition of the C function, not an interprocedural constant-prop version.

Comment: I was working under the assumption that the assembly was actually correct. That assumption is, in fact, invalid.

Comment: I think the code is at least much closer to correct if you switch the first two variables.

Comment: I have edited the question based on my GCC results, which were similar, but differed in three places (after changing short to long)

Comment: You forgot to change `short` to `long` in your edit.  Fixed that for you.  I wonder if the OP typed it out by hand and got a bunch of things wrong?  That would explain the missing commas (which I hadn't noticed until I saw the diff in your edit that added them in.)